# Alter media caption/description conflict in Wordpress?

Tags: images, uploads, media, captions

When uploading an image, Wordpress reads the description meta data from the jpg via `wp_read_image_metadata` and inserts it into the `post_content` field when adding the attachment via `media_handle_upload` or `media_handle_sideload`

But when adding a image to the editor in Wordpress, it looks for the caption in the `post_excerpt` field via `image_media_send_to_editor`

What I'd like is just some continuity, in that when our images are uploaded, the field populated by WordPress for the images meta description is the one used for the caption when placing an image in the editor.

Can anyone suggest a way I can hook into any of these functions in order to match up the process? I don't really care which way I fix it, although I tend to think that `post_excerpt` leads to less database overhead since it's a 'smaller' field.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like this Trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22768

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this will work for you:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', function( $attachment_id ){
    $a = get_post( $attachment_id );
    if ( is_object( $a ) && 'image' === substr( $a->post_mime_type, 0, 5 ) )
        wp_insert_attachment( array( 'ID' => $a->ID, 'post_excerpt' => $a->post_content ) );

});
```

or with less queries:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', function( $attachment_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    if( ! empty( $attachment_id ) )
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
                                       SET post_excerpt = post_content 
                                       WHERE ID = %d LIMIT 1", $attachment_id ) );

});
```

where the *description* (`post_content`) is copied to the *caption* (`post_excerpt`) when the `add_attachment` is fired just after the attachment has been inserted (added).